# I am unable to automatically login to a website using Python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to connect to a website automatically using my python script. But somehow it is throwing me an error.

Code which I am using:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from getpass import getpass
username = input("Enter you CUID:")
password = getpass("Enter you CUID password:")
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
driver1 = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\\PrakashJha\\Documents\\webdriver\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver")
driver1.get("https://directory.corp.intranet/cmsviewer/login.html?page=/cmsviewer/MAL/index.html%3Fkey%3DY8P-CRS")
cuid_user = driver1.find_element_by_name("f_loginname")
cuid_user.send_keys(username)
password_cuid = driver1.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/table[3]/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/form/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/input")
password_cuid.send_keys(password)
enter_button = driver1.find_elements_by_name("frn_login")
enter_button.submit()*
```

the site I am trying to connect requires a VPN access.

and the error I am receiving is:

```
C:\Users\PrakashJha\PycharmProjects\new\venv\Scripts>python Cms_connect.py
Enter you CUID:acxxxx
Enter you CUID password:
Cms_connect.py:10: DeprecationWarning: use options instead of chrome_options
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PrakashJha\PycharmProjects\new\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 76, in start
    stdin=PIPE)
  File "C:\Users\PrakashJha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 775, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\PrakashJha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 1178, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Cms_connect.py", line 10, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
  File "C:\Users\PrakashJha\PycharmProjects\new\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Users\PrakashJha\PycharmProjects\new\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 83, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2i6o.png)

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Provide the full path of chromedriver till .exe

example:

```
driver1 = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\\PrakashJha\\Documents\\webdriver\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe")
```

Also in you code whatever option you set for driver will not be set for driver1

If you want to use options along with driver path

```
webdriver.Chrome(driver_path, options=chrome_options)
```

Comment: thanks Ravi.
 Found the solution:
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\\Users\\PrakashJha\\Documents\\webdriver\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe')

Answer (score 0):

Found Solution:
 webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\Users\PrakashJha\Documents\webdriver\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')

or

webdriver.chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\PrakashJha\Documents\webdriver\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')